# Initialize vectors and std

Tags: c++, vector, std

If I have a var

```
vector<myClass> myVector;
```

Is it already initialized?, ie, may I add (push_back) inmediately elements or I should call the constructor in the following way?

```
myVector = vector<myClass>();
```

On the other hand, is it the same `std::vector<myClass>` and `vector<myClass>`?

Comment: No you don't need to do `myVector = vector<myClass>();` myVector is initialized to an empty vector by default contructor and you can start adding elements using `push_back`

Comment: You can't use just "`vector`" without `using namespace std;` (or some other namespace that has a `vector`) or having defined `vector` somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation

```
MyClassType a;
```

actually calls `MyClassType`'s default constructor, if it has one. So yes, a `vector` is already initialized and ready to use.
Your second snippet:

```
myVector = vector<myClass>();
```

Actually creates a new, temporary `vector`, which is default constructed, and then calls `myVector`'s copy assignment operator `operator=()`.

In this regard, C++ is different from many other languages. For example, in Java, you'd need to do `MyClassType a = new MyClassType()`. This is not necessary in C++. Whenever you declare a value of class type with automatic storage<sup>1</sup>, the object is automatically default constructed. This is also true for class members. Let's say you have:

```
class A {
    std::vector<int> m_myVector;
};
```

Then there is no need to initialize `m_myVector` - it's done automatically whenever you instantiate an object of class `A`.

It's different when you allocate objects on the heap:

```
// Note: DON'T use raw pointers in actual code - use smart pointers instead.
// Just for illustration purposes.

// This is just a pointer to an A, it's not yet initialized.
A* myA; 

myA = new A(); 
// now myA points to a heap allocated, default constructed A object.

// Note that you can omit the default constructor's `()` and just write:
myA = new A;
```

Heap allocating an object is actually closer to what Java does under the hood. Anyway, when writing proper C++, you rarely need to heap allocate, and you wouldn't ever do it with a `vector`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Automatic storage: Put simply, anything you create in C++ without using `new/delete` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it already initialized?

Yes (assuming this is `std::vector`). As with any sane class, all its constructors (including the default constructor used here) put it into a well-defined state. At this point, it's a valid, empty vector.

> I should call the constructor in the following way?

That's not calling the constructor (at least, not on `myVector`). Constructors are called automatically during object initialisation; there's no way to call it a second time. This creates another empty vector, then copy-assigns it to `myVector`.

> On the other hand, is it the same std::vector and vector?

Presumably, this is `std::vector`, dumped into the global namespace with an evil `using namespace std;`. To avoid doubt, confusion and potential amibiguity, you should avoid doing that, remove any rogue using-directives, and always refer to it as `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case

```
vector<myClass> myVector;
```

there is no need to call default constructor separately.

You can call `push_back` and other methods.